# передача текста из textview в кастомизированный список (listview)

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Есть главный экран с двумя view элементами : `editText` и `Button`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть отдельный файл файл разметки - `item.xml`, который на выходе должно подхватывать `list view` и размещать в элементы списка , вот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот так приблизительно должен выглядеть второй, конечный экран с полученной информацией:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Желательно, чтобы информация сохранялась стекообразно,а крестик ее удалял и выбрасывал из стека,а на место удаленной двигалась актуальная инфа.
Я понимаю, что вопрос обширный и за один день навряд  справлюсь, поэтому размещу коды Активитис, чтобы в конечном итоге было еще кому-то полезно, если справлюсь и тема разрастется.
MAIN

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
EditText text;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
     button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

SECOND

```
public class Second extends MainActivity{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);

}
```

Должны быть созданы регулирующие классы и адаптеры, но не понимаю как сложить этот пазл, главное начать)поэтому буду двигаться маленькими шажками, пока не пойму как это работает. Сильно не ругайте)

Comment: Пример работы со списками можно найти в «Android. Программирование для профессионалов» Брайн Харди, Билл Филлипс. Только читать нужно с самого начала, а не переходить сразу к главе, в которой рассматриваются списки. **Это если есть знания Java Core.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример работы с адаптерами http://androiddocs.ru/vidzhet-recyclerview-prostoj-primer/
Для простоты можно линейный список, у него есть готовый адаптер для строковых массивов

Не претендую на правильность решения

Активити1: текстовое поле и кнопка. По клику добавляешь значение своего текстового поля в массив. Если будут проблемы с передачей массива в другое активити можно его в учебных целях сделать статическим и обращаться Активи1.array

Активити2: Пишешь адаптер со своим itemview (в твоем случае это кнопка и текстовое поле. На онклик вешаешь удаление элемента) и вроде как все)